# relational database design - normalization and relationships

Tags: php, mysql, database, relationships, database-normalization

I am new to designing databases and I am not sure if I implemented normalization and relationships correctly in the design of the database for my application.

The application being designed works with shopping lists and products, and will use the database as follows:

- Users log in via facebook to the website.
- There is a large table with millions of "product codes". Each product code represents a different product (ex. Apple, TV, cellphone, toothbrush, etc).
- Users are able to create various shopping lists, and each shopping list would contain one or more "product code"s.

I have **"attempted"** to create two different designs for the database in an attempt to deduce which one might be better for the scenario. One using a one-to-many relationship, and one many-to-many relationship, both of which link **shopping_list** to **product**:

[image]

**QUESTIONS:**

1. **REGARDING one-to-many:** Given that there would be millions of different product id's, wouldn't the **one-to-many** design produce a lot of redundant information in the **assigned_products** table? The products table would have fields similar to:

   ```
    ________________________________________________
   |assigned_p_id | shopping_list_id | product_code |
   |--------------+------------------+--------------|
   |      1       |        1         |   aa11aab    |
   |--------------+------------------+--------------|
   |      2       |        1         |   zz1bbbb    |
   |--------------+------------------+--------------|
   |      3       |        2         |   aa11aab    |
   ```

as you can see, `aa11aab` was repeated twice because someone else created a shopping list with the same item, hence I wonder if this redundancy would create database issues with the amount of unnecessary space each repeated product_code would take?

2. **REGARDING many-to-many:** The diagram seems to be taking away redundancy by having the table **shopping_list_products** store id values rather than repeating the product_code, HOWEVER, would this cause a performance loss when retrieving the information? I assume that a few **joins** would have to take place between the tables so that each individual user gets all their shopping lists and the product codes within that shopping lists.
3. **Generally speaking:** Might there be any errors in my relationships / normalization? (I am a newbie in this area)

Comment: So your second diagram solves the problem as the Product stays agnostic to the user as it should be, and there's no escape from using the bridge relation between the shopping_list and product, which is completely OK. Without bridge table shopping list and product will never know each other.

Comment: Shopping_list_products also needs a pk. As it stands it should be both fks. You might want a quantity in there too.

Comment: @LoztInSpace I'm a bit new to designing databases :), so would "Shopping_list_products" then contain it's own auto-incremented ID (which would be it's primary key). Also regrding the "both fks", do you mean that I would have two foreign keys in that table? I wasn't even sure if that was possible (allowed by the MySQL server)

Comment: No need for its own id, yes 2 fks

Comment: Re *"id values rather than repeating the product_code"* Ids & product_codes are both just values. There is no "redundancy" in the latter. In a given DBMS one might introduce ids for optimization. Normalization does not involve introducing new column names.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions for where to get started.

You'll need a table to store information about purchases. In the data you can see that Wile E Coyote has purchased a Dyno-might and a Piano...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `purchase` (
    `id`           int unsigned      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id`      int unsigned      NOT NULL,
    `item_id`      int unsigned      NOT NULL,
    `quantity`     double            DEFAULT 1,
    `price`        double            NOT NULL,
    `qwhen`        datetime          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES product(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB Comment='Purchases';

purchase data
+----+---------+------------+----------+--------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | product_id | quantity |  price | created             |
+----+---------+------------+----------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |          1 |        1 | 100.00 | 2016-07-02 20:42:13 |
|  1 |       1 |          3 |        1 | 734.23 | 2016-07-02 21:23:40 |
| .. | ....... | .......... | ........ | ...... | ................... |
+----+---------+------------+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

You will also need a table to store information about products. I'm assuming you're selling physical products so I've added `ean`, `upca` and some other columns that might be helpful.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
    `id`                 int unsigned      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `manufacturer_id`    int unsigned      NOT NULL,
    `ean`                int unsigned      NOT NULL,
    `upca`               int unsigned      NOT NULL,
    `upce`               int unsigned      NOT NULL,
    `name`               varchar(100)      NOT NULL,
    `height`             double            DEFAULT NULL,
    `width`              double            DEFAULT NULL,
    `depth`              double            DEFAULT NULL,
    `weight`             double            DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturer_id`) REFERENCES manufacturer(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB Comment='Item master file';

product data
+----+-----------------+---------------+--------------+--------+------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+
| id | manufacturer_id | ean           | upca         | upce   | name       | height | width | depth | weight |
+----+-----------------+---------------+--------------+--------+------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|  1 |               1 | 1234567890123 | 123456789012 | 123456 | Dyno-might |   12.0 |   1.0 |   1.0 |    0.5 |
|  2 |               1 | 2345678901234 | 234567890123 | 234567 | UltraLaser |   96.0 |  96.0 |  96.0 |  450.0 |
|  3 |               2 | 3456789012345 | 345678901234 | 345678 | Piano      |   36.0 |  60.0 |  72.0 |  375.0 |
| .. | ............... | ............. | ............ | ...... | .......... | ...... | ..... | ..... | ...... |
+----+-----------------+---------------+--------------+--------+------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+
```

When we sell things to people it's nice to address them formally so we should have a table of valid salutations. The `user` table will have a foreign key to this table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `salutation` (
    `id`           varchar(5)     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB Comment='Salutations';

salutation data
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| Mr.  |
| Mrs. |
| Miss |
| Ms.  |
| Dr.  |
| Rev. |
| .... |
+------+
```

Name suffixes are part of a person's name so we will make that part of the `user` table and provide a foreign key to this table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `suffix` (
   `id`           varchar(5)     NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB Comment='Suffixes';

suffix data
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| Sr. |
| Jr. |
| II  |
| III |
| IV  |
| ... |
+-----+
```

And of course we have users - though it might be more appropriate to call them customers.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
    `id`              int unsigned   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `facebook_id`     int unsigned   NOT NULL,
    `email`           varchar(255)   NOT NULL,
    `salutation_id`   varchar(5)     NOT NULL,
    `first_name`      varchar(50)    NOT NULL,
    `middle_name`     varchar(50)    DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_name`       varchar(50)    NOT NULL,
    `suffix_id`       varchar(5)     DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`salutation_id`) REFERENCES salutation(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`suffix_id`) REFERENCES suffix(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB Comment='Users';

user data
+----+-------------+------------------------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | facebook_id | email                  | salutation_id | first_name | middle_name | last_name | suffix_id |
+----+-------------+------------------------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |   123456789 | coyote_guy32@gmail.com | Mr.           | Wile       | E           | Coyote    | NULL      |
| .. | ........... | ...................... | ............. | .......... | ........... | ......... | ......... |
+----+-------------+------------------------+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially doing the same thing in both cases. In the first case you are mapping `shopping_list_id` to `product_code`, in the second case you are mapping it to `product_id`. Whether you use `product_code` or `product_id` it seems like they are both foreign keys representing the `product` entity. In both cases, to arrive at the product row, you'll have to join against the `products` table using that field.

As a general rule, you should map the two `id` columns (your 2nd option) so that in both cases joins are done using integer primary keys. This not only makes for more efficient storage and index, it also makes those joins a lot faster.

Also, as one of the comments pointed out, you should add the auto-increment primary key to the `shopping_list_products` table.

On a side note, for a naming convention, you might want to consider always naming the primary keys with `id`. For example, instead of having `products.product_id`, you'd have `products.id` and so on for every table.